# VSCode extensions are not able to find certain file in order to run

Tags: visual-studio-code

At startup, the GitHub Copilot Extension is unable to start because it can't find

```
/home/####/.vscode-server/bin/somebignumber/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js
```

When I go to check what that file contains, it doesn't actually exist!
I want to use a certain extension to change my VSCode background which relies on this file as well, but it's unable to work. GitHub Copilot also doesn't work. Clicking on activate Copilot button doesn't do anything.

What does this file contain and what do I do to fix it?

Using WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 btw.

Comment: does GitHub Copilot work locally

Comment: magically github copilot works after spamming the activate button a few times. for the other wallpaper extension, it still throws those errors.